# How can I find a value that doesn't exist in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simplified table called `Bookings` that has two columns `BookDate` and `BookSlot`. The `BookDate` column will have dates only (no time) and the `BookSlot` column will contain the time of the day **in intervals of 30 minutes** from 0 to 1410 inclusive. (i.e. 600 = 10:00am)

How can I find the first slot available in the future (not booked) **without** running through a loop?

Here is the table definition and test data:

```
Create Table Bookings(
    BookDate DateTime Not Null,
    BookSlot Int Not Null
)
Go

Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-01',0);
Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-01',30);
Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-01',60);
Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-01',630);
Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-02',60);
Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-02',90);
Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-02',120);
```

I want a way to return the first available slot that is not in the table and that is in the future (based on server time).

Based on above test data:

- If the current server time was **1st Jul, 00:10am**, the result should be **1st Jul, 90min** (01:30am).
- If the current server time was **2nd Jul, 01:05am**, the result should be **2nd Jul, 150min** (02:30am).

If there are no bookings in the future, the function would simply return the closest half-hour in the future.

--

SQL Fiddle for this is here:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e93d/1

Comment: Insert Into Bookings(BookDate,BookSlot) Values('2014-07-01',630); please explain Bookslot value of 630 and subsequent values..

Comment: OP did explain that already, the number represents the 30-minute intervalled slot so if `600`=10:00am then `630` would be 10:30am

Comment: @mmhasannn, Please see the explanation above. BookSlot is in minutes of a day. 630 means 10:30 am. Just divide by 60 to get the time.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gKVFtkfW -- Was originally an answer because it wouldn't fit in a comment, but this is better. There's some code there that's half way there, it's just datetime conversion I'm unsure of.

Comment: what version of SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated but try this:

```
WITH DATA 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    ORDER BY BOOKDATE, BOOKSLOT) RN 
         FROM   BOOKINGS) 
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN T.BOOKSLOT = 1410 THEN Dateadd(DAY, 1, BOOKDATE) 
         ELSE BOOKDATE 
       END Book_Date, 
       CASE 
         WHEN T.BOOKSLOT = 1410 THEN 0 
         ELSE BOOKSLOT + 30 
       END Book_Slot 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 T1.* 
        FROM   DATA T1 
               LEFT JOIN DATA t2 
                      ON t1.RN = T2.RN - 1 
        WHERE  t2.BOOKSLOT - t1.BOOKSLOT > 30 
                OR ( t1.BOOKDATE != T2.BOOKDATE 
                     AND ( t2.BOOKSLOT != 0 
                            OR t1.BOOKSLOT != 630 ) ) 
                OR t2.BOOKSLOT IS NULL)T
```

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1a320/13) example.

**Explanation**

This solution contains 2 parts:

1. Comparing each line to the next and checking for a gap (can be done easier in SQL 2012)
2. Adding a half an hour to create the next slot, this includes moving to the next day if needed.

**Edit**

Added `TOP 1` in the query so that only the first slot is returned as requested.

**Update**

Here is the updated version including 2 new elements (getting current date+ time and dealing with empty table):

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2014-07-01', 
        @Slot INT = 630 
DECLARE @time AS TIME = Cast(Getdate() AS TIME) 

SELECT @Slot = Datepart(HOUR, @time) * 60 + Round(Datepart(MINUTE, @time) / 30, 
                                            0) * 30 
                      + 30 

SET @Date = Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)


;WITH DATA 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    ORDER BY BOOKDATE, BOOKSLOT) RN 
         FROM   BOOKINGS 
         WHERE  BOOKDATE > @Date 
                 OR ( BOOKDATE = @Date 
                      AND BOOKSLOT >= @Slot )) 
SELECT TOP 1 BOOK_DATE, 
             BOOK_SLOT 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN RN = 1 
                      AND NOT (@slot = BOOKSLOT 
                      AND @Date = BOOKDATE) THEN @Date 
                 WHEN T.BOOKSLOT = 1410 THEN Dateadd(DAY, 1, BOOKDATE) 
                 ELSE BOOKDATE 
               END Book_Date, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN RN = 1 
                      AND NOT (@slot = BOOKSLOT 
                      AND @Date = BOOKDATE) THEN @Slot 
                 WHEN T.BOOKSLOT = 1410 THEN 0 
                 ELSE BOOKSLOT + 30 
               END Book_Slot, 
               1   AS ID 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 T1.* 
                FROM   DATA T1 
                       LEFT JOIN DATA t2 
                              ON t1.RN = T2.RN - 1 
                WHERE  t2.BOOKSLOT - t1.BOOKSLOT > 30 
                        OR ( t1.BOOKDATE != T2.BOOKDATE 
                             AND ( t2.BOOKSLOT != 0 
                                    OR t1.BOOKSLOT != 1410 ) ) 
                        OR t2.BOOKSLOT IS NULL)T 
        UNION 
        SELECT @date AS bookDate, 
               @slot AS BookSlot, 
               2     ID)X 
ORDER  BY X.ID
```

Play around with the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1a320/60) and let me know what you think.

Comment: This solution is missing 2 elements: 1. It doesn't check the current Date & time and so it may return a slot in the past. 2. It cannot deal with an empty table (no slots).  Are these issues critical? If so, let me know and I'll add them in.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Gidil. But yes, both issues are critical. Available booking must be in the future only and a table could be theoretically empty. The actual table in production also has the length of the booking (in 30 min intervals), facility ID where the booking happens as well as user and other data. Bookings for all facilities are stored here. But the logic can be simplified to the above tables.

Comment: I'll start with dealing with the empty table, it's relatively easy. The current date would need to be transformed to the codes used or would it be available from the system?

Comment: You can use the getdate() function to get the current date - though you would need to get the minutes of the day as well.

Comment: OK, working on it. It's slightly complicated so it might take me a few minutes to iron it all out ;-)

Comment: I tried with Date='2014-07-01' and Slot=305 and the result was 660. The correct answer should have been 330.

Comment: @navigator, you are right. Small mistake, posting the fix within a minute :-)

Comment: @navigator ,fixed. Please note that if you "manually" enter a slot you may not get a correctly rounded slot in the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57916/discussion-between-navigator-and-gidil).

Answer (score 1):

Below is one method that will allow bookings up to 256 days in the future, and allow for an empty Booking table.  I assume you are using SQL Server 2005 since your BookDate is dateTime instead of date.
In any case, you might consider storing the slots as a complete datetime instead of separate columns.  That will facilitate queries and improve performance.

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = '2014-07-01 00:10:00'; 

WITH T4 
     AS (SELECT N 
         FROM   (VALUES(0), 
                       (0), 
                       (0), 
                       (0), 
                       (0), 
                       (0), 
                       (0), 
                       (0)) AS t(N)), 
     T256 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 AS n 
         FROM   T4 AS a 
                CROSS JOIN T4 AS b 
                CROSS JOIN T4 AS c), 
     START_DATE 
     AS (SELECT Dateadd(DAY, Datediff(DAY, '', @now), '') AS start_date), 
     START_TIME 
     AS (SELECT Dateadd(MINUTE, Datediff(MINUTE, '', @now) / 30 * 30, '') AS 
                start_time), 
     DAILY_INTERVALS 
     AS (SELECT N * 30 AS interval 
         FROM   T256 
         WHERE  N < 48) 
SELECT TOP (1) Dateadd(DAY, future_days.N, START_DATE) AS BookDate, 
               DAILY_INTERVALS.INTERVAL                AS BookSlot 
FROM   START_DATE 
       CROSS APPLY START_TIME 
       CROSS APPLY DAILY_INTERVALS 
       CROSS APPLY T256 AS future_days 
WHERE  Dateadd(MINUTE, DAILY_INTERVALS.INTERVAL, 
              Dateadd(DAY, future_days.N, START_DATE)) > START_TIME 
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                      FROM   DBO.BOOKINGS 
                      WHERE  BOOKDATE = START_DATE 
                             AND BOOKSLOT = DAILY_INTERVALS.INTERVAL) 
ORDER  BY BOOKDATE, 
          BOOKSLOT;
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e93d/11)

Comment: Hi @Dan, thanks for the effort. From what I can gather, you're generating a virtual table of 256 days with 48 entries in each table, joining it with bookings and then finding the empty slots. It seems like a bit of overkill. I think a loop might just be faster. In my actual table, there are dozens of facilities where bookings can be made - so the above function would be called once for each facility to find the next available slot. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012 and later, you can use the `lead()` function.  The logic is a bit convoluted because of all the boundary conditions.  I think this captures it:

```
select top 1
       (case when BookSlot = 1410 then BookDate else BookDate + 1 end) as BookDate,
       (case when BookSlot = 1410 then 0 else BookSlot + 30 end) as BookSlot
from (select b.*,
             lead(BookDate) over (order by BookDate) as next_dt,
             lead(BookSlot) over (partition by BookDate order by BookSlot) as next_bs
      from bookings b
     ) b
where (next_bs is null and BookSlot < 1410 or
       next_bs - BookSlot > 30 or
       BookSlot = 1410 and (next_dt <> BookDate + 1 or next_dt = BookDate and next_bs <> 0)
      )
order by BookDate, BookSlot;
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I tried using it on SQL Fiddle (SQL 2012) but it returned an error. Could also be an error in SQL fiddle.

Comment: Gives error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'"

Answer (score 0):

Using a tally table to generate a list of originally available booking slots out 6 weeks (adjustable below):

```
declare @Date as date = getdate();
declare @slot as int  = 30 * (datediff(n,@Date,getdate()) /30);

with 
slots as (
    select (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by s)-1) * 30 as BookSlot
    from(
        values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1) -- 4 hour block
    )slots(s)
    cross join (
        values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1) -- 6 blocks of 4 hours each day
    )QuadHours(t)
)
,days as (
    select (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by s)-1) + getdate() as BookDate
    from (
        values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)  -- 7 days in a week
    )dayList(s)
    cross join (
        -- set this to number of weeks out to allow bookings to be made
        values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)      -- allow 6 weeks of bookings at a time
    )weeks(t)
)
,tally as (
    select
         cast(days.BookDate as date) as BookDate
        ,slots.BookSlot              as BookSLot
    from slots
    cross join days
)

select top 1 
     tally.BookDate
    ,tally.BookSlot
from tally
left join #Bookings  book
   on tally.BookDate    = book.BookDate
  and tally.BookSlot    = book.BookSlot
where book.BookSlot is null
  and ( tally.BookDate > @Date or tally.BookSlot > @slot )
order by tally.BookDate,tally.BookSlot;

go
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT a.bookdate, ((a.bookslot/60.)+.5) * 60
FROM bookings a LEFT JOIN bookings b 
ON a.bookdate=b.bookdate AND (a.bookslot/60.)+.50=b.bookslot/60.
WHERE b.bookslot IS null
```

Comment: I wrote that as a comment, that doesn't work if the next available slot is between now and the first used slot after it.

Comment: @Jayvee you miss the currenttime part in your solution

Comment: @Jayvee, just tried it. It gives a wrong result.
2014-01-01:120, 2014-01-02: 150